# Delivery Note in Magento PDF

Tags: invoice, pdf

I'm trying to add a custom note to Magento's invoice PDF documents. I'm using the Deliverynote plugin.

I am trying to add this piece of code to the invoice.php code but I'm not getting any results.

```
$noteId = Mage::registry('current_invoice')->getOrder()->getData('delivery_note_id'); 

$this->_note = Mage::getModel('deliverynote/note')->load($noteId)->getNote();
```

Here is the Github location https://github.com/drewhunter/ShipNote

I also tried doing this.

```
        $newnote = new Dh_Deliverynote_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Note();

        $newnote->_initNote();
        $var = $newnote->$_note;

        $vars = serialize($var);

        $this->insertDocumentNumber(
            $page,
            Mage::helper('sales')->__('Invoice # ') . $vars . $invoice->getIncrementId()
        );
```

How would I insert that into the PDF?

Comment: I don't know the plugin, but I assume there's a very interesting part that includes an order-object where $noteId is defined. :)

Comment: Yes there is I added that into the question above.  How would I insert that into the pdf though?

Comment: What version of Magento are you using this on?

Comment: Instead of delivery_note_id I think it should be ship_note_id see https://github.com/drewhunter/ShipNote/blob/master/src/app/code/community/Dh/ShipNote/Model/Observer.php#L52

Comment: It actually was delivery_note_id.

Answer (score 1):

You weren't that far off, I think.

I'm going to assume you're editing `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice`.

In this model there's a variable `$invoice`, that contains all the invoice relevant data. It also has a relation to the order object, which you can retrieve using `$invoice->getOrder()`.

That module you're using adds a relation to the order but you don't need it. Instead, we just load up the note itself using `Mage::getModel('shipnote/note')->loadByOrder($invoice->getOrder());` which then has a magic `getNote()` method that will retrieve the actual note.

```
$shipnote = Mage::getModel('shipnote/note')->loadByOrder($invoice->getOrder());
if ($shipnote) { 
    $shipnote->getNote();  // use this wherever you want it to go.
}
```

Comment: This looks good. Shouldn't it be deliverynote/note?  I still cannot get it to work though.  It just gives me a blank page when I try to print the invoice.  It's because of the first line of code.

Comment: The culprit is the loadByOrder bit.  If I just do a regular load on a random number I can get the note.  I wonder why loadByOrder is failing.

Comment: You can try using `->loadByOrderId($invoice->getOrderId())`, see if that works. As to your earlier comment, the config.xml defines the model alias as `shipnote`, not deliverynote.. The above should work if you use `shipnote/note`, either with loadByOrder or loadByOrderId. Mind you, the `ship_note_id` attribute needs to be in the Order object, so if you adjusted that attribute in any way it wont work, you'll need to adjust the Model as well.

Answer (score 0):

So what actually ended up working was this.  It might have worked from the original $order variable in invoice.php but I am leaving it as is since it is working.

```
       $order3 = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order->getIncrementId());

       $shipNoteId = $order3->getData('delivery_note_id');

       $note = Mage::getModel('deliverynote/note')->load($shipNoteId)->getData('note');
```

Then in adding it into the invoice pdf I created a insertNote function.

```
        $this->insertNote(
        $page,
        Mage::helper('sales')->__('USPS INSTRUCTIONS: ') . $note
        );
```

I also made a video showing how to do this in Magento.  http://youtu.be/bjZ31AlmN2I